# Issue with parsing list of HTML with lxml and requests

Tags: python, html, html-parsing, lxml, python-requests

I have a list of URLs stored in a variable `href`.  When I pass it through the below function, the only returned recipe_links come from the first URL in `href`.  Are there any glaring errors with my code? I'm not sure why it wouldn't loop through all 20 URLs I have stored in `href`.  The returned results that I get for the first URL in `href` are retrieved as expected, but I can't get the loop to the next URL.

```
def first_page_links(link):
    recipe_links = []
    recipe_html = []

    for x in link: 
        page_request = requests.get(x)
        recipe_html.append(html.fromstring(page_request.text))

        print recipe_html

        for x in recipe_html:
            recipe_links.append(x.xpath('//*[@id="content"]/ul/li/a/@href'))

            return recipe_links
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try pushing out your second loop and your `return` line so that no redundant iteration happens and the final list is properly returned, something like the following:

```
from lxml import html
import requests as rq

def first_page_links(links):

    recipe_links = []
    recipe_html = []

    for link in links:
        r = rq.get(link)
        recipe_html.append(html.fromstring(r.text))

    for rhtml in recipe_html:
        recipe_links.append(rhtml.xpath('//*[@id="content"]/ul/li/a/@href'))

    return recipe_links
```

Let us know if this works.

**EDIT:**

Consider the following:

```
y_list = []
final_list = []
for x in x_list:
    y_list.append(x)
    for y in y_list:
        final_list.append(y)
```

This is your function, simplified. Assuming in `x_list` you have 3 URLs, what happens is the following:

1. `x1` is appended to `y_list`.
2. `y_list` is processed with only `x1` so far, so `x1` alone is appended to `final_list`. `final_list` now contains: `[x1]`
3. `x2` is appended to `y_list`.
4. `y_list` now contains `x1` and `x2`. ***Both*** are processed and appended to `final_list`. `final_list` now contains: `[x1, x1, x2]`.
5. `x3` is appended to `y_list`. `y_list` now contains `x1`, `x2`, and `x3`.
6. See where this is going? :)

Since your second loop, which processes the items in the first list, is inside the first loop, which adds *incrementally* to the first list, the second loop will process your first list *on every iteration of the first loop*. This makes it a redundant iteration.

There are many ways to execute what you wanted to do, but if you're just appending to lists and need a one-pass loop on both, the above fix was all that's needed.

Comment: This works exactly how I wanted it to! Thanks!  Could you explain why the way I had it created redundant iteration?

Comment: Thank you so much for the thorough explanation.

Answer (score 4):

Watch where the `return` is placed. You probably want to return after all the loops are finished:

```
def first_page_links(link):
    recipe_links = []
    recipe_html = []

    for x in link: 
        page_request = requests.get(x)
        recipe_html.append(html.fromstring(page_request.text))

        print recipe_html

        for x in recipe_html:
            recipe_links.append(x.xpath('//*[@id="content"]/ul/li/a/@href'))

    return recipe_links
```

Comment: So I just tried this and I am getting tons of repeat results.

Comment: @Barnaby: Is it possible to get the html edited into your post as well?

Comment: This is how the recipe links are coming in:`['recipe1', 'recipe1', 'recipe2', 'recipe1', 'recipe2', 'recipe3',  'recipe1', 'recipe2', 'recipe3', 'recipe4',   'recipe1', 'recipe2', 'recipe3', 'recipe4', recipe5'....]`

Comment: For some reason I can't see the HTML, it shows up as `[<Element html at 0x10fc88418>]
[<Element html at 0x10fc88418>, <Element html at 0x10fc5a368>]
[<Element html at 0x10fc88418>, <Element html at 0x10fc5a368>, <Element html at 0x112aaf998>]
[<Element html at 0x10fc88418>, <Element html at 0x10fc5a368>, <Element html at 0x112aaf998>, <Element html at 0x112ab9d60>]
[<Element html at 0x10fc88418>, <Element html at 0x10fc5a368>, <Element html at 0x112aaf998>, <Element html at 0x112ab9d60>, <Element html at 0x112e0c100>]` This is why I think I am getting the above output for the recipe links

Comment: How about posting the URL you're trying to scrape? Also, check my answer if it helps.